# how to move UI element with storyboard?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I've worked with Opacity property in storyboard 
but I cant figure it out how to move an UI element like grid stackpanel button ..... in c#?
(I am writing the storyboard in c# not in  xaml )

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on your actual layout: Do you want to animate a button in a Grid or in a Canvas (could animate the Margin property or the Canvas.Left attached property, respectively)? Do you want to animate the property itself or a transform (the latter would animate a RenderTransform - specifically a TranslateTransform). You would use the RenderTransform if you still want to refer to the "old" position.

One simple way is:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myButton" 
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="1" To="350" 
                       Duration="0:0:10" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Yellow">
       <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="100" Height="30" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" />
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you use blend for storyboard ..i have genrated a code for stackpanel movement towards right ..just check it..

[you can go through this video aslo it's very good](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flIbZ_1dJZ0) it will perfectly work in your case

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="hello">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Name="hello" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Text="hello1" FontSize="50" />
        <Button Content="Button" FontSize="50" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and to start do this on button click..

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }
```

for better understand just read about how to use blend..